# "Undo" operation in Visual studio 2010 making a mess out of code?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My Visual Studio has been causing problems with "undo" of late, to a disastrous effect.

The pattern is such that

- I make some changes
- I try to undo change
- The change actually removes a large block of code and inserts/removes other parts of the code which often makes the code file after applying Undo totally worthless.
- Further attempts to Undo or Redo just messes up the code further.

This problem doesn't consistantly occur, but from time to time it happens suddenly.

I do C++ programming in Visual Studio. I don't know if it's any problem with the version.

What can cause this behavior in Visual Studio 2010, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Any reason why not switch to the newest VS? There exists even 2015 preview version now... This sounds like some bug in the old version, but I've never encountered it myself.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in an IDE, which, when the IDE is closed-source, is not something that can be solved through programming.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I used VS 2010 for years, never encountered such issues and highly doubt it that such a core function would have a bug of that magnitude that could go unnoticed for such a long time...

Comment: How are you invoking the undo command? By pressing Ctrl-Z or by clicking on the undo button?

Comment: @DeanKuga Ctrl+Z, I never use any other form of Undo. I tried using Google to find an answer, but the only similar question I found was [this one on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/b9aab698-0429-4769-869f-75aac60f6bdd/undo-does-not-work-screws-up-my-code). Same problem except it's on a Mac, and no answer. I'm not sure if it matters or not, but I'm using C# instead of C++ like the OP says here. I'm convinced it's something to do with the editor in VS.

Comment: Did you try starting VS in safe mode to disable everything that could potentially cause such behavior?

Comment: @DeanKuga It still happens when I start Visual Studio using `devenv.exe /safemode`

Comment: To make this perfectly clear, are you stating that undo changes parts of code that were not even modified since the document was opened? Or is it just undoing to some earlier point than you'd expect/desire?

Comment: @DeanKuga I am attempting to undo some changes to a code file, and rather than removing/adding text where it should be, it starts removing other sections of the code and adding or removing the changes in the middle of other code. For example, if I erase a line of code then hit Ctrl+Z, it erases half a page worth of code and inserts the removed line in the middle of another line of code. Hitting Redo to try to reverse that will re-insert the line of code, but frequently removes additional lines or puts it in the wrong place. I'll try to get an exact use case next time it happens

Comment: @DeanKuga I used Ctrl+Z.

Comment: Are you sure, Service Pack 1 for Visual Studio 2010 is installed?

According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509/en-us there was a bug titled **533093: CTRL+BACKSPACE deletes too much text**.

Comment: I had problem with shortcuts like F12 and Alt + F12. I was able to fix it by resetting to default from Tools -> Options -> Keyboard

Comment: @Rachel Have you been able to consistently reproduce the bug, some sequence of editing that would trigger it 100%?

Comment: @sashoalm I cannot reproduce it on demand, however given a few hours programming at my normal speed (with plenty of Ctrl+Z) will almost always result in the bug occurring. I think it may happen more frequently when I remove a line and try to Ctrl+Z it back in, but I am not positive.

Answer (score 1):

Please post your issue in https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback ; as a more specialized audience may be able to help you.

As pointed out in the comments:

- It is **closed-source**, nobody can really go and debug the code for you.
- Your version is some years old, and problem may have been fixed in recent versions.
- There is a [visual studio service pack 1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509/en-us) that you may need to install

If your issue isn't resolved by patching or upgrading your version, please consider posting your issue to  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback or changing your editor.